# Get to neighbor jquery

Tags: jquery

I have part of HTML. I need write jquery script, which change "Error" to "Valid"

```
Phone: <input type="text" name="Phone" title="title1" value="(XXX) XXX-XXXX"><br>
<span>
 <span role="alert">
 Error!//REplace here to "Valid"
 </span>
</span>
```

My Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var test = $('[title="title1"]');
test.neighbor.child[0].text("Valid");//How write here?

});

</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: @adeneo hahaha, just fill in this comment with everything RocketHazmat said.  Good to know.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the 2nd next sibling element and its child

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = $('input[title="title1"]');
    test.next().next().children().text('valid')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4vPxg/)

Another way is to find the next span sibling like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = $('input[title="title1"]');
    test.nextUntil('span').last().next().children().text('valid')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ee2wg/)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var xEle = $('input[title="title1"]');
   xEle.next().next().find("span[role='alert']").text('valid')
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ee2wg/2/)